# Split names and dates within the same cell into 2 different cells (using multiple delimiters)

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have single (merged) cells that have this pattern:

FirstName (possible MiddleName) LastName (" " OR ", " OR " / ") DD/MM/YY

For example:

```
John Doe 21/01/2022
John Johasson Doe, 21/01/2022
etc...
```

I would like to split such cell using VBA and pasting the full name and the date into their own individual cells

The main delimiter here seems to be the date sinceit starts with a number since names can't takes those but I'm not sure how to achieve splitting the cell content.

So far I was using this:

```
Workbooks(workbook1).Worksheets("sheet").Range("whatever cell num").Value = Split(Workbooks(workbook2).Worksheets("sheet").Range("whatever cell num").Value, ", ")(0)
    Workbooks(workbook1).Worksheets("sheet").Range("whatever cell num").Value = Split(Workbooks(workbook2).Worksheets("sheet").Range("whatever cell num").Value, ", ")(1)
```

It used to work fine for its purpose until I started coming across signatures that don't involve commas to separate names and dates

Is there a solution that doesn't involve creating a function a looping through the string?

Comment: Have you considered using [`.TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.TextToColumns)?

Comment: Does it work over multiple workbooks? Most examples of its usage comes within the same workbook/sheet

Comment: If what you show is the variability, you can easily do this with worksheet formulas.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I do need it to be done with VBA as I am working on a macro for other users. formulas aren't an option unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro

- splits off the last space separated segment which is the date

  - Do this by reversing the string, then splitting into two.
  - split the date by the "/", and create a date variable
- Remove any commas that may or may not be in the string
- write the results next to the original

  - minor coding changes would enable overwriting the original

***Note: if speed is an issue due to the number of rows in the worksheet, this should be rewritten using VBA arrays instead of repeated worksheet cell references***

```
Sub SplitIt()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant
    Dim sName As String, dt As Date
    
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Set rg = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each c In rg
    v = Split(StrReverse(c), " ", 2)
    w = Split(StrReverse(v(0)), "/")
    dt = DateSerial(w(2), w(1), w(0))
    sName = Replace(StrReverse(v(1)), ",", "")
    
    With c
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = sName
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = dt
    End With
Next c
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I feel like this is a different issu altogether but I get a type mismatch if transfering from xlsb to xlsm for instance. I get the error at the DateSerial line.

Comment: @IKindaNeedAHand I cannot reproduce your problem.  The macro runs with no errors no matter the workbook type.  What precisely did you do?  Which line produces the error?

Comment: It is my bad. Essentially, what was happening is that some of the merged cells (some name + date) had the name somehow not separated from the date via space messing the DateSerial. Ideally, I should work on making sure it wouldn't be an issue but I'm not sure how to achieving that.
If you have some time over chat, I would like to expand on that and learn but otherwise, your method does work perfectly, thank you sir.

Comment: @IKindaNeedAHand If that is the only issue, and especially if there is nothing else in the string that looks like a date, it may be simplest to split the contents using a Regular expression.  OTOH, one way to enforce proper data entry is by using a User Form.

Comment: I unfortunately have no control over the files I'm working with. I'm also not really versed with regex

Comment: @IKindaNeedAHand I don't understand.  How does control over the files affect your ability to answer my question about other possible variations in the string you are trying to parse?

Comment: I have 2 template files. I make a tool to transfer data from one template to another and vice versa. I cannot enforce proper data entry, I can just deal with the data I'm given.

Comment: @IKindaNeedAHand Can't you examine the file before you process it in order to determine what the lines might look like? Without having some idea of the different formats that might be used, I don't think my supplying more code will be useful.

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by examining. I don't think I can realistically account for all possible typos

Comment: @IKindaNeedAHand  Will the date always be at the end?  Will the date always be in the format of dd/mm/yy?  Will there be anything else in the string that looks like dd/mm/yy?  if dates are in different formats, what might those formats be?  Will it be simpler for you to manually adjust the non-conforming data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241620/discussion-between-ikindaneedahand-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 0):

A different way using InStrRev.

Sub Split_Name_Date_test()

Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim c As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    Set c = sh.Cells(i, "A")

    TheText = Trim(c.Value)
    LastSpace = InStrRev(TheText, " ")
    TheName = Trim(Mid(TheText, 1, LastSpace))
    TheDate = Mid(TheText, LastSpace + 1)

    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = TheName
    c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "'" & TheDate
Next i
```

End Sub