# Account for most possible date variants/formats

Tags: excel, vba

I have created recently a thread asking for how to split names and dates seperated by various menas (sometimes it's a space, sometimes it's a comma, etc) here's the thread: [Split names and dates within the same cell into 2 different cells (using multiple delimiters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805859/split-names-and-dates-within-the-same-cell-into-2-different-cells-using-multipl)

And while the function works when the date is set in the same manner, I'm encountering increasingly more variants. So aside from delimiters, there is an issue in date format which creates an error.

I lack knowledge in VBA/Excel macros, what would be a good mean to recognize/account for possible date formats and transfer them through a regular dateSerial?

```
02 January 2022
January 02 2022
2022/02/01
01/02/2021
etc.
```

Comment: If at all possible an easier solution would be to validate the data coming in forcing a certain format instead of trying to parse all possible formatting.

Comment: It's unfortunately impossible on my end. Files come to me as they are, I have no control over the template they use or the formating they chose for their date.

Comment: What about ambiguous dates?  In other words, how would you interpret `01/02/2021`?  Is that `1-Feb-2021` or `2-Jan-2021`?

Comment: Im extremely sorry I haven't noticed your answer earlier @RonRosenfeld. And unfortunately, I have no answer for that either, supposedly date is simply copied based on a delimiter as I mentioned in my other thread but it is not so straightforward at this point. Do you have any ideas as to how to fix that on my end?

Comment: If --you** do not know how to interpret ambiguous dates, there's no way for a **computer** to figure that out. You will have to obtain information from the file source as to whether dates are being entered in MDY or DMY format.  If you could be certain that all the dates (the one's with just numbers) are in the SAME format, it is possible if some are not ambiguous and there is at least one non-ambiguous date.  But if that is not the case, you will have to obtain that information from the file or file author.

Answer (score 0):

*CDate* eats them all if the month name is localised (here Danish):

```vb
? CDate("02 Januar 2022")
02-01-2022 
?CDate("Januar 02 2022")
02-01-2022 
?CDate("2022/02/01")
01-02-2022 
? CDate("01/02/2021")
01-02-2021
```

But there is no way it can tell if 01/02/2021 is Jan 2. or Feb 1.

Comment: How could I implement it into the code of the thread I linked earlier? If you don't mind? I might just add conditionals at that point

Comment: That's is not going to be easy. You can't even just replace month names with numbers, as _May_, _April_, _June_, and _August_ are common names as well. But doable? Yes.